# CSS change font style after declaring it, relation with before selector

Tags: html, css

I've some span elements where i make usage of the before pseudo selector. Works fine.
My problem is that the content of my `:before` need to have a different font style e.g no text-decoration etc.
Can not overwrite it after declaring it on my span elements.

```
#MyElement span
{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#MyElement span + span:before
{
  content: "|";
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dyJXw/

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Did you mean `#MyElement span:before` on that second rule? Your current rule translates as 'style the before pseudo element of any span that comes after another span inside an element with an id of MyElement'

Comment: this is the right behavior.

Comment: You should post your HTML code, too.

Comment: This is a css problem. I think some people had some similar trouble.

Comment: CSS as such does not do anything. It affects HTML or XML documents, so it *is* relevant to post the essential part of markup, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`text-decoration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-decoration) property is not inherited, but it behaves in a manner that somewhat looks like “forced inheritance”: “When specified on or propagated to an inline element, it affects all the boxes generated by that element”. So even if the `:before` pseudo-element has no `text-decoration` or it has `text-decoration: none` set on it, the generated content is affected by the `text-decoration` of the parent (the real `span` element).

However, the specification adds: “Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.” So you get rid of the underline for the generated content by changing your second rule to this:

```
#MyElement span + span:before
{
  content: "|";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: +1 I did not think about display. went for absolute positioning... :)

Answer (score 1):

One hack is to make the pseudo element's `position:absolute`, so that it does not flow with its parent content and inherit its attributes.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwd97/)

From Example:-

```
#MyElement span {
    text-decoration: underline;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:5px;
}
#MyElement span + span:before {
    content:'|';
    left:-5px;
    position:absolute;
}
```